# Can I use singleShot(true) to make a running QTimer to stop after next shot?

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I have a `QTimer` triggering periodical events.

I don't want to stop the timer directly because I want to sync some special signals to the last event.

Can I achieve this by setting `setSingleShot(true)` on this `QTimer` so that its next shot will be a single shot, and the timer stops after the next shot?

**Edit:**
It seems to work. but `setSingleShot(true)` seems not atomic: I sometimes observe 2 shots before the timmer stops.

Comment: You may try to do it and check results :)

Comment: @SaZ Seems to work. But I'm not sure if the last shot follows the same interval.

Comment: You probably see between 0 and 2 shots due to the order that messages arrive in the message queue of the main thread loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Yes you can. In fact, there is no difference between "regular" and single-shot timers - other than this flag. Each time the timer times out, it check the single-shot flag. If it is set, the timer unregisters itself and thus doesn't fire again until you restart it.